# spark mllib apply function to all the elements of a rowMatrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a rowMatrix `xw`

```
scala> xw
res109: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@8e74950
```

and I would like to apply a function to each of its elements:

`f(x)=exp(-x*x)`

The type of element of the matrix can be visualized as:

```
scala> xw.rows.first

res110: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [0.008930720313311474,0.017169380001300985,-0.013414238595719104,0.02239106636801034,0.023009502628798143,0.02891937604244297,0.03378470969100948,0.03644030110678057,0.0031586143217048825,0.011230244437457062,0.00477455053405408,0.020251682490519785,-0.005429788421130285,0.011578489275815267,0.0019301805575977788,0.022513736483645713,0.009475039307158668,0.019457912132044935,0.019209006632742498,-0.029811133879879596]
```

My main problem is that I can not use map on vector

```
scala> xw.rows.map(row => row.map(e => breeze.numerics.exp(e)))
<console>:44: error: value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
              xw.rows.map(row => row.map(e => breeze.numerics.exp(e)))
                                     ^

scala>
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is assuming you know you've actually got a `DenseVector` (which seems to be the case).  You can call `toArray` on the vector, which has a map, and then convert back to a `DenseVector` with `Vectors.dense`:

`xw.rows.map{row => Vectors.dense(row.toArray.map{e => breeze.numerics.exp(e)})}`

You could do this on a `SparseVector` as well; it will be mathematically correct, but converting to an array could be extremely inefficient.  Another option would be to call `row.copy` and then use `foreachActive`, which would make sense for both dense and sparse vectors.  But `copy` may not be implemented for the specific `Vector` class you are using, and also if you don't know the type of vector, you can't mutate the data.  If you really need to support sparse & dense vectors, I'd do something like:

```
xw.rows.map{
  case denseVec: DenseVector => 
    Vectors.dense(denseVec.toArray.map{e => breeze.numerics.exp(e)})}
  case sparseVec: SparseVector =>
    //we only need to update values of the sparse vector -- the indices remain the same  
    val newValues: Array[Double] = sparseVec.values.map{e => breeze.numerics.exp(e)}
    Vectors.sparse(sparseVec.size, sparseVec.indices, newValues)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for the vectors.dense class do you suggest me to use the provided line of code or not?    Can you write the code also per the second part of the answer? I am scala beginner so it is not too easy to follow

Comment: @Donbeo I updated the answer a little bit.  If you are sure you have DenseVectors, go with the first answer.  If you might have sparse or dense, you can use the second one, but note that even that doesn't handle other possible implementations of Vector.  (eg., it doesn't handle `VectorUDT`)